# How to pass parameter to another url?

Tags: php

I have this page structure:

```
|- Careers
    |- Office 1
    |- Office 2
    |- Office 3
```

Each office page will have an anchor to send the user to a `job-description.php` template, so I need to pass the `id` of the job that the user has choosen.

On this `job-description.php` I need to get the `id` of that job that was choosen.

How would be the best way to pass this parameter to the other page using php?

Answer (score 0):

Use a query string when you link to job-description.php, so you'd have links like this:

```
job-description.php?job_id=1
job-description.php?job_id=2
job-description.php?job_id=3
etc.
```

In job-description.php, then you can use $_GET to get the job_id. Make sure to sanitize it since it's in the URL and could be changed by a devious person. I'd get the value for job_id and sanitize it like this:

```
if( isset($_GET['job_id']) ){
    $job_id = filter_var( sanitize_text_field($_GET['job_id']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
```

Then you can do whatever you need to do with $job_id.

Also just to note why I used "job_id" as the name of the parameter because IIRC "id" is a protected parameter used by Wordpress so you have to use something else.